# Split string into two strings by delimiter

Tags: c, string, split, malloc

I try split a string into two strings by delimiter with this code

```
int indexOf(char *msg, char c) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; msg[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (msg[i] == c)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

char *substring(char *msg, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    int length = endIndex - startIndex;
    char *input = (char *)malloc(length * sizeof(char) + 1);

    int i;
    for (i = startIndex; i != endIndex; i++) {
        input[i - startIndex] = msg[i];
    }
    input[endIndex] = '\0';

    return input;
}
```

In `main` I have:

```
index = indexOf(msg, ':');

first = substring(line, 0, index - 1);
second = substring(line, index + 2, strlen(line));
```

This code produces correct output when I Test it with valgrind. The substring allocated in second variable produces an error.

Where is the problem with this function? Is there another way to split string into two strings?

```
char *msg = readMessage(stdin);
index = indexOf(msg, '\n');
char *line, *first, *second; 

line = substring(msg, 0, index);
```

end valgrind `Address 0x5203a52 is 5 bytes after a block of size 13 alloc'd`

**EDIT**: There is another bug for

```
index = indexOf(line, ':');
```

Now the valgrind error is in substring on line `input[endIndex] = '\0';`:

```
Invalid write of size 1
```

**EDIT**: Solution of my code that have two bugs

in main

```
index = indexOf(msg, ':');
```

should be

```
index = indexOf(line, ':');
```

and in substring

```
input[endIndex] = '\0';
```

should be

```
input[length] = '\0';
```

thanks to all

Comment: What error? And, by the way, don't cast `malloc` returns.

Comment: You are casting the `malloc`, also, should that not be `strlen(msg)`? Where does `line` come in?

Comment: could look into `strtok` ? Always initialise pointer variables to `NULL` for sanity. Have you debugged it? What is the code for `readMessage`? I think the pointer variable returned from function is getting clobbered as that is allocated within the function's stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

- `input[endIndex] = '\0';` uses the wrong index. It should be `input[length] = '\0';`
- in `main()`, you should not make implicit assumptions about the return value of `indexOf`.  The posted code invokes undefined behavior if `:` is not found in `line`:

Here is a safer version:

```
int index = indexOf(line, ':');
if (index >= 0) {
    // found the `:` separator
    char *first = substring(line, 0, index);
    if (line[index + 1] == ' ') {
        index++;  // skip the space after the :
    }
    char *second = substring(line, index + 1, strlen(line));
    ...
}
```

You can use `strcspn()` instead of `indexOf` to extract the parts with fewer tests:

```
char *msg = readMessage(stdin);
size_t index = strcspn(msg, "\n");
char *line = substring(msg, 0, index);
...
```

`strcspn()` returns the number of characters upto but not including and of the characters in its argument string. It returns the same value as `indexOf()` if the character is present (except for the `size_t` type instead of `int`), and it returns the length of the string if it isn't, which is what you want in your case.

Comment: the check if line have the ':' I have in other code

Comment: @mardon: 4386427 actually spotted an error in your fragment from the `main` function. It should be `index = indexOf(line, ':');`

Answer (score 1):

```
index = indexOf(msg, ':');
                ^^^
                line ?
```

Here

```
second = substring(line, index+2, strlen(line));
```

you assume that that line is longer than index+2. Something you should check to avoid a zero in the `malloc` call. In other words - if the delimiter is the last character, you run in to problems.

You should add a check of the value returned by `malloc`

```
if (!input)
{
    // Print error message
    exit(1);
}
```

BTW - take a look at `strdup` and `memcpy` or `strncpy`

Comment: Please do not advocate the use of `strncpy`.  https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Comment: @chqrlie - The problem with the termination is correct. I'm not sure any standard C function solves that - do you know one? Your link solves it by writing a custom function using for  C++. Doing the same in C using `strncpy`